# Get label from value in radio buttons list fieldtype

Tags: fieldtypes

Ok I know how to list radio buttons and use it to display a particular value:

```
{% set newsType = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('newsType') %}
{% for option in newsType.settings.options %}
    {% if option.value == 'newsValue' %}
        <h3 class="news-type">{{  option.label }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

(I am not in an existing entry context.)
So I would like to know if there is a shortcut to directly get this label from the value? Like that syntax :

```
{% set newsTypeLabel = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('newsType').option('newsValue').label) %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a macro and use that as a "shortcut":

```
{% macro optionLabel(fieldHandle, optionValue) %}

    {%- set field = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle(fieldHandle) %}
    {%- for option in field.settings.options %}
        {%- if option.value == optionValue %}
            {{- option.label }}
        {%- endif %}
    {%- endfor %}

{%- endmacro %}
{% import _self as macros %}

<h3>{{ macros.optionLabel('newsType', 'newsValue') }}</h3>
```

Comment: Interesting yes, I did not know about twig macros yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the selected radio button’s label, in the context of an existing entry, you can do this:

```html
{% if entry.newsType|length %}
    <h3 class="news-type">{{ entry.newsType.label }}</h3>
{% endif %}
```

(Documented here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/radio-buttons-fields#templating)

Comment: Thx Brandon but thats the problem: I am not in the existing entry context : I have an entry type filter, I want to display the entry type (radio buttons) label that I am filtering on (from craft.request.segment(2)).

Comment: In that case the other answer is your best bet :)